# VideosJs Player with YouTube Skin

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, youtube

Website:
http://videojs.com/

How can I use the YouTube Skin on the frontpage?
I'd really love to customize the player to look like that one on the frontpage.

Can someone explain how to do this please?

PS: I must be blind, i cant find the youtube skin on the webpage :/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The CSS for the skin is available in the source code  : http://www2.videojs.com/css/tube-css/tube.css.
The sprite used in css is available here : http://www2.videojs.com/css/tube-css/tubesprite.png .
According to the [doc](http://videojs.com/docs/skins/) you just have to replace the default class `vjs-default-skin` by the  new one , in your case : `tubecss`

So include the appropriate css in your page and do something like :

```
<video class="video-js tubecss" ...>
```

Note : On the videojs website the skin class is applied to the video tag's wrapper. I have not tested this , but both solution should be valid.